# Php Define Websend

Tags: php

I am having a problem with the define only effecting the 1 part of the code. I would appropriate some help. Thanks Joshua

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){

$ports = define("PORT", "2467");;
$ws = new Websend("127.0.0.1");
$ws->password = "";

if($ws->connect()){
    $ws->doCommandAsConsole("say Hey Pve(".$mcusername.")");
}
$ws->disconnect();
echo end($ports);

$ports = define("PORT", "2466");;
$ws = new Websend("127.0.0.1");
$ws->password = "";

if($ws->connect()){
    $ws->doCommandAsConsole("say Hey Hub(".$mcusername.")");
}
$ws->disconnect();
echo end($ports);

}
```

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: Use `$port = 2467;` instead of `define()` if you intend to change the port number.

Comment: You probably misunderstood the purpose of define: [http://nl3.php.net/define](http://nl3.php.net/define)

Comment: Maybe this websend thing requires constants and nothing else.

Comment: i know but i need it so that it will send a commmand to one server then another server but both on diff ports

Answer (score 0):

you can redefine constant use [runkit-constant-redefine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-constant-redefine.php) if you have runkit extension installed [runkit extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) so in this case you can rewrite your code next

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){

$ports = define("PORT", "2467");;
$ws = new Websend("127.0.0.1");
$ws->password = "";

if($ws->connect()){
    $ws->doCommandAsConsole("say Hey Pve(".$mcusername.")");
}
$ws->disconnect();
echo end($ports);

$ports = runkit_constant_redefine("PORT", "2466");;
$ws = new Websend("127.0.0.1");
$ws->password = "";

if($ws->connect()){
    $ws->doCommandAsConsole("say Hey Hub(".$mcusername.")");
}
$ws->disconnect();
echo end($ports);

}
```

Comment: How would I get runkit for windows xp

Comment: From Runkit manual: [Installation](http://php.net/manual/en/runkit.installation.php)
A DLL for this PECL extension is currently unavailable.
You have to compile the DLL yourself or try to use some compiled .dll like [https://github.com/Crack/runkit-windows](https://github.com/Crack/runkit-windows)